# Get delivery status from GraphServiceClient

Tags: graphserviceclient

I have working code (See below) that successfully sends email. But I would like to add the ability to update status if there was an issue with the delivery (partner email error, such as "no such email address here"). Is that possible? I've seen that by saving to the sent folder and using a unique id (GUID) I could identify my message, would that allow me to get any failed/success messages?

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(GetCredentials());
                var saveToSentItems = false;
                graphServiceClient
                    .Users[NOREPLY_SENDER_ID]
                    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync().Wait();
```